# How do I get pagination working with exclusiveStartKey for dynamodb aws-sdk-go-v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go, aws-sdk-go-v2

I'm trying to create a pagination endpoint for a dynamodb table I have. But I've tried everything to get the exclusiveStartKey to be the correct type for it to work. However, everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.

example code:

```
func GetPaginator(tableName string, limit int32, lastEvaluatedKey string) (*dynamodb.ScanPaginator, error) {
    svc, err := GetClient()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        Limit:     aws.Int32(limit),
    }

    if lastEvaluatedKey != "" {
        input.ExclusiveStartKey = map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "id": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{
                Value: lastEvaluatedKey,
            },
        }
    }

    paginator := dynamodb.NewScanPaginator(svc, input)
    return paginator, nil
}
```

Edit:

Okay so I'm creating a API that requires pagination. The API needs to have a query parameter where the lastEvaluatedId can be defined. I can then use the lastEvaluatedId to pass as the ExclusiveStartKey on the ScanInput. However when I do this I still received the same item from the database. I've created a test.go file and will post the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
)

type PaginateID struct {
    ID string `dynamodbav:"id" json:"id"`
}

func main() {
    lastKey := PaginateID{ID: "ae82a99d-486e-11ec-a7a7-0242ac110002"}

    key, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(lastKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), func(o *config.LoadOptions) error {
        o.Region = os.Getenv("REGION")
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    svc := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *dynamodb.Options) {
        o.EndpointResolver = dynamodb.EndpointResolverFromURL("http://localhost:8000")
    })

    input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName:         aws.String("TABLE_NAME"),
        Limit:             aws.Int32(1),
        ExclusiveStartKey: key,
    }

    paginator := dynamodb.NewScanPaginator(svc, input)

    if paginator.HasMorePages() {
        data, err := paginator.NextPage(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println(data.Items[0]["id"])
        fmt.Println(data.LastEvaluatedKey["id"])
    }
}
```

When I run this test code. I get this output:

```
&{ae82a99d-486e-11ec-a7a7-0242ac110002 {}}
&{ae82a99d-486e-11ec-a7a7-0242ac110002 {}}
```

So the item that is returned is the same Id that I am passing to the ScanInput.ExclusiveStartKey. Which means it's not starting from the ExclusiveStartKey. The scan is starting from the beginning everytime.

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to create a database call that I can do a query per page of results. So on my first page, I limit everything to 10 results, when I do a call for the second page I need to provide an ExclusiveStartKey where Dynamodb will start the scan from. However, I'm not sure why it's not working as I am providing the ExclusiveStartKey in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

so basically what you need to do is to get the  [LastEvaluatedKey](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/613f9c99f5889935eea3ac4e51fe72948bb69470/service/dynamodb/api_op_Scan.go#L309) and to pass it to [ExclusiveStartKey](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/613f9c99f5889935eea3ac4e51fe72948bb69470/service/dynamodb/api_op_Scan.go#L98)

you can not use the scan paginator attributes because it's not exported attributes, therefore instead I suggest that you use the returned page by calling [NextPage](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/613f9c99f5889935eea3ac4e51fe72948bb69470/service/dynamodb/api_op_Scan.go#L498)

in the following snippet I have an example :

```
func GetPaginator(ctx context.Context,tableName string, limit int32, lastEvaluatedKey map[string]types.AttributeValue) (*dynamodb.ScanOutput, error) {
    svc, err := GetClient()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        Limit:     aws.Int32(limit),
    }

    if len(lastEvaluatedKey) > 0  {
        input.ExclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey
    }

    paginator := dynamodb.NewScanPaginator(svc, input)
    
    return paginator.NextPage(), nil
}
```

keep in mind that `paginator.NextPage(ctx)` could be `nil` incase there is no more pages or you can use [HasMorePages()](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/613f9c99f5889935eea3ac4e51fe72948bb69470/service/dynamodb/api_op_Scan.go#L493)

Comment: How would I do this on a GET request using query parameters? So let's say my query parameter has the id of the lastEvaluatedKey. Then in go I would need to create the map[string]types.AttributeValue and set it to {"id": {"Value": queryparam.id}} ? I'm not sure how to create the map[string]types.AttributeValue correctly

Comment: you don't need to create it yourself you need just to pass it from output to input and of the first time you can create just empty one map[string]types.AttributeValue{} and that's why in the code we check if length > 0

Answer (score 0):

The `aws-sdk-go-v2` DynamoDB query and scan paginator constructors have a bug ([see my github issue, includes the fix](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1452)).  They do not respect the ExclusiveStartKey param.

As an interim fix, I copied the paginator type locally and added one line in to the constructor:  `nextToken: params.ExclusiveStartKey`.

Comment: Okay great. Glad I'm not the only one. I did find a fix for my use case, however. You can just use the normal svc.Scan and parse the ExclusiveStartKey there and it works fine.